# DOMMouseScroll event.wheelDelta is undefined on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, zooming

I am trying to add zooming to an SVG document but the DOMMouseScroll event.wheelDelta is undefined on Firefox. I have also tried using event.originalEvent.wheelDelta, this is also undefined. My code works in Chrome. This is the code I am using , any help would be appreciated.

```
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" 

if (theSvgElement.attachEvent)  
    theSvgElement.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, zoomViaMouseWheel)
else if (theSvgElement.addEventListener)  
    theSvgElement.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, zoomViaMouseWheel, false)

function zoomViaMouseWheel(mouseWheelEvent) {  
    if(mouseWheelEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
        alert('scrolling up ! ' + mouseWheelEvent.wheelDelta);
    }
    else{
        alert('scrolling down ! ' + mouseWheelEvent.wheelDelta);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel

Comment: I am getting results now using event.detail but it is very slow.              function zoomViaMouseWheel(mouseWheelEvent) {  
 if(mouseWheelEvent.detail  > 0) {
        alert("scrolling up ! " + mouseWheelEvent.detail);
    }
    else{
        alert("scrolling down ! " + mouseWheelEvent.detail);
    }